# Zend_Form renders all fields as text

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend_Form form, with some custom decorators, like this:

```
$decorators = array();
$decorators[] = new Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper(array());
$decorators[] = new Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors;
$decorators[] = new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-item'));
$decorators[] = new Zend_Form_Decorator_Label(array('class' => 'form-label'));
$decorators[] = new Zend_Form_Decorator_Callback(array(
    'callback' => function($content, $element, $options) {
        return sprintf('<div class="form-row">%s</div>', $content);
    },
    'placement' => false
));
$this->setElementDecorators($decorators);
```

The problem is, that all of the fields are rendered as text inputs. Why does it happen?

EDIT: I discovered, that it doesn't render all the inputs necessarily as text inputs, but renders them with type of the first input in form. Here is example of a form that i use(the decorators are set int parent's init):

```
<?php

class Form_Users_Add extends Form_Base {
    protected $pbxs = array(1 => 'Element 1', 2 => 'Element 2');

    public function init() {
        $monitors = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('prefered_screen_count');
        $monitors->setCheckedValue(2);
        $monitors->setUncheckedValue(1);
        $monitors->setLabel('two_monitors');
        $this->addElement($monitors);

        $pbx = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('asterisk_id');
        $pbx->setMultiOptions($this->pbxs);
        $pbx->setLabel('users_asterisk_id');
        $this->addElement($pbx);

        parent::init();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the form code? And as a side question: why use a `Callback` decorator for the row? Why not use `HtmlTag`, like you do for the item itself? Just curious.

Comment: I edited the question. And I am using Callback, because I couldn't get two HtmlTag's working - probably I'm doing something wrong, but they just got replaced.

Comment: Aaah, there is a trick for using multiple instances of the same decorator class on a single element: you need to alias the decorator name. Ex: `array(array('my-item' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'some-class')),`. Then use a different alias - say `my-row` -  on the `HtmlTag` decorator for the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay! I have solved the issue! The cause was that I used INSTANCES of classes, not the names. This way every element was using the same instance of the decorator.